# Right arm muscle cramps and inability to move or feel

Tags: muscle-tremor-twitch, spasms, cramps

So starting with yesterday, my girlfriend started getting some weird muscle contractions on her right arm. It would start shaking while not being able to control it or feel anything. I have to mention that all of this is painless, it doesn't last more than 30 seconds and it happens twice a day (until now).

Have anyone ever experienced this before? We went to see a doctor but they asked us to take some more tests and since today (in Romania) is a public holiday, we can't get nowhere until tomorrow.

Would highly appreciate any insight. I'm freaking out more than my girlfriend does :(

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Seeking doctor's advice was the right course of action. We can't really make a diagnosis over the internet and the tests you are going to make will surely help your doctor determine the cause and find a solution.